# Automatic Type Conversion in ColdFusion 11

Tags: coldfusion

I am migrating an application from ColdFusion 9 to ColdFusion 11.

In the existing code there is an assignment of a variable to `false`:

```
<cfset VARIABLES.roleTypeId = false >
```

And then, farther down, a function that expects this variable to be numeric:

```
<cffunction name="rolesForStudy" >
    <cfargument name="id" hint="Study Id">
    <cfargument name="roleTypeId" default="#VARIABLES.roleTypeId#" type="numeric"/>
</cffunction>
```

I inherited the code, and I cannot defend the original programmer's decision to set it up this way -- but, in short, it *worked* in ColdFusion 9, and it *doesn't work* in ColdFusion 11 (returning a data type error). I assume that ColdFusion 9 was automatically converting `false` to `0`.

My question: Is there a configuration setting that I can change in ColdFusion 11 to make it do the conversion like ColdFusion 9 did? Or will I have to fix this code, along with probably lots of other similar examples throughout the application? Neither I nor our ColdFusion administrator has been able to find any information about this in the ColdFusion Administrator interface, the ColdFusion documentation, or online.

**Edit in Response to Adam Cameron in comments**

I have created a file that consists of the following 10 lines (and nothing else):

```
<cfset VARIABLES.roleTypeId = false >
<cfoutput>
<p>#rolesForStudy( 1, VARIABLES.roleTypeId )#</p>
</cfoutput>

<cffunction name="rolesForStudy" >
    <cfargument name="id" hint="Study Id">
    <cfargument name="roleTypeId" default="#VARIABLES.roleTypeId#" type="numeric"/>
    <cfreturn "It worked" >
</cffunction>
```

When I execute it in ColdFusion 9, it displays the words "It worked".

when I execute it in ColdFusion 11, it returns the following error message:
**If the component name is specified as a type of this argument, it is possible that either a definition file for the component cannot be found or is not accessible.**

Comment: Whatever your issue is, it's not a problem casting false to a numeric (it'll cast to 0 just fine). This behaviour had not changed in ColdFusion 11. Can you provide a proper repro case which demonstrates what you're seeing? Also provide the exact error (copy and pasted from screen). Also might pay to read this: http://blog.adamcameron.me/2013/09/short-self-contained-correct-compilable.html

Comment: Holy f*** (just ran your updated code here. I get the same. WTF?! Looking into it)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe you will have to fix the code. There are no settings (that I know of at any rate) that alter the way CF handles boolean types. You should be able to change the assignement above from "false" to 0 and your function code will work. However I suspect elsewhere you might have something like `<cfif variables.roletypeID IS "False">` which will then be broken as it is in truth looking for a string - which *also* works (ha).  CF's handling of a myriad of values as boolean (0 or not 0, true, false, yes and no) is a legacy of it's origin. It's convenient at times but definitely leads to things like this.

Meanwhile I wonder if this change of behavior is a new bug or the fixing of an old bug. In my view passing "false" as an argument and having it read as numeric seems inconsistent so the *new* way of doing it seems right to me. However, many many languages treat 0 or not 0 as default values for true and false.

EDIT:

According to Adam's comments below, my example of code where someone would say:

```
<cfif somevar IS "false">
```

...would work even if somevar was indeed numeric. His example (useful) is that:

```
#0 is "False"#
```

...will output "yes" - so CF is recasting the string "false" to a zero under the hood for comparison. That makes my example incorrect.

My answer is still correct I believe.  The issue he's running into is that the argument passed to his function - being of the type "boolean" is throwing an error because the function expects a numeric value. But Adam's point and example makes me think perhaps this behavior is a bug - since it appears CF is not casting to a number before checkign the type  (something it *did do* in CF 9 according to the Joe).

Comment: Thanks. I want to see if any other answers come in before I mark any of them as correct -- but I've already upvoted your reply. Your response matches what I assumed, but I was hoping someone more familiar with ColdFusion than I would have a solution that would let me avoid a lot of code refactoring.

Comment: Yep... there may be some slick Java guy on here that knows some obscure property :)

Comment: This is a good lesson in maintaining data types across applications. As duncan points out, Numberformat does work (Oddly val() works in Railo but doesn't work in CF (9, at least--anyone wanna test?). Still, while Duncan's solution works, bandaids have a habit of breaking in unexpected ways. It is better to be consistent.

Comment: Mark, sorry, but the issue is not what the OP is claiming it is. For example this outputs `Yes`: `<cfoutput>#0 is "false"#</cfoutput>`. And it has since about CFMX7 (before which an inline expression like that would have been a syntax error. CF - all versions - will always cast a boolean to a numeric when necessary. This is *not* the answer to the issue (and have downvoted it, sorry)

Comment: Adam, yeah I see that you are correct in the versions I'm able to check. I edited my answer and added your information. I wonder if "strict type checking" has any bearing here?

Comment: Ooh... lemme check that. (update: actually, erm... where does one set that? I only see the CFC-type checking one in CFAdmin)

Comment: That's the one I'm thinking of.

Comment: @AdamCameron - did you check that setting? I have not had the time, but I can do it this afternoon.

Answer (score 3):

NumberFormat is your saviour, credit going to [this comment](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/908-coldfusion-numberformat-exploration.htm#comments_5183) on one of Ben Nadel's articles.

```
<cfset VARIABLES.roleTypeId = false>
#NumberFormat(VARIABLES.roleTypeId)# <!-- = 0 -->
<cfset VARIABLES.roleTypeId = true>
#NumberFormat(VARIABLES.roleTypeId)# <!-- = 1 -->
```

So you should be able to either convert it to the expected numeric type before calling the function, or just doing

```
<cfargument name="roleTypeId" default="#NumberFormat(VARIABLES.roleTypeId)#" type="numeric">
```

Comment: Good find, I found it really surprising that `NumberFormat` does work, but `Val()` does not (in ACF9, it does in Railo). Still, I hope the OP just corrects the code. I did just find that `Int()` works as well though. Still, I hope the OP just fixes the old code.

Comment: You don't need to cast it. See my comment on question and Mark's answer.

Comment: @cfqueryparam - What do you mean [`val()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-6e64.html) does not work? There are no numeric characters at the beginning of "false" (or "true" for that matter), so it should return zero (0). Does it do something differently in Railo?

Comment: @Leigh Prior to this question, I had never tried Val(true) to see what would happen. I maintain compatible values across applications, but since NumberFormat() does work, I had kind of expected Val() to work, so tried it. On CFLive.net, CF9 returns 0 for both true/false (as val does for every non-numeric value) but Railo returns 1 for true.

Comment: @cfqueryparam - Hm.. it makes sense for `NumberFormat` to implicitly convert `false` to a number. That is in line with CF's rules for [data conversion](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec09af4-7ff3.html). However, [the purpose of `val`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-6e64.html) is different: *Converts numeric characters that occur at the beginning of a string to a number.* Given that, the Railo result sounds wrong.

Comment: @Leigh Oh, I agree. However it doesn't make sense that Int does either. I also just found out, for cf9 via cflive.net, that `Round()` and `Ceiling()` convert to 0 and 1 respectively as `NumberFormat()` does. Val appears to be the outlier.

Comment: @cfqueryparam - Those functions always convert the input into numbers implicitly, so there is no real surprise there. Just CF's typical data conversion stuff. The `val` function operates differently. It searches a *string*, looking for numeric characters. So the result should not be the same.

Answer (score 1):

I've raised this as a bug in ColdFusion 11: "[Type coercion failure when passing boolean to a numeric arg](https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3877068)".

I recommend you work around this by taking the type check off the argument. This is probably the lowest-impact fix.

This is also a rare case in which I'd add a comment to code, explaining *why* you've taken the type checking off.

Apologies to Joe, Mark & Duncan for emphatically contradicting what they were finding. That said, I don't agree that their answers are the best approach here ;-)