# Error when passing a list to a function expecting a numeric argument-worked in CF9 but not in CF11

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, coldfusion-11

For whatever reason(right or wrong), we have a function declaration like:

```
<cffunction name="findaccount" access="public" returntype="struct">
    <cfargument name="roles" type="numeric" required="true" default="1">
    ...
</cffunction>
```

Then the function is invoked by

```
<cfinvoke method="findaccount" returnvariable="stAccountDetails">
    <cfinvokeargument name="roles" value="1,2">
</cfinvoke>
```

Regardless the original intention of passing a list to a function expecting numeric, this code has been working in CF9 for long time. Recently we decided to upgrade to CF11 and the code throws the following exception:

```
Detail: If the component name is specified as a type of this argument, it is possible that either a definition file for the component cannot be found or is not accessible. 
Message: The ROLES argument passed to the findaccount function is not of type numeric.
```

When searching, I found a similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27447751/automatic-type-conversion-in-coldfusion-11). My question is: is taking the type check off the argument (like suggested by Adam Cameron) the best workaround for my case considering there are many invocations like this?

Comment: I suggest changing the type to string, because that's what 1,2 is.  Then check for non-numeric values inside your function and do what you need to do.  If it's any consolation, I've also have had ColdFusion upgrades cause less than perfect code to break.  I find that annoying.  If it was going to break, it should have done so immediately so I could have done something at the time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope, don't do what I said.

If you follow through [the link to the bug](https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3877068) I raised (mentioned in my answer), someone at Adobe clarified what is going on. It impacts the other situation and yours as well:

> In CF 11 a new application setting was introduced:
>   strictnumbervalidation = "true|false" By default the value of this
>   setting is "true", which introduces strict number validation. Setting
>   this value to "false" explicitly , will make the validation behave in
>   old way.

Comment: Interesting. Did not know that.  (If the docs are to be believed, the new [application setting](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/Application+variables)  affects `IsValid, cfargument, cfparam and cfform`. @sunrise - I am curious how you were using it with "lists". From what I read, it sounds like it was designed to allow specific types of formatting for numbers,  not arbitrary "lists" of numbers. For example, I ran a quick test and CF9 accepted "1,2,3" but rejected "1,2,3,5".

Comment: @Leigh, it's cos it's interpretting 1,2,3 as a date (probably Jan 2, 1903), then casting it to a number. But *obviously* whilst 1,2,3 is a date... 1,2,3,5 is not. Silly you! ;-)